# Replace default Datatables script to most recent [custom buit] one

Tags: api, upgrade, developer, javascript

How do one properly replace default 3-rd party packages without loosing changes after updates?

Namely, in need of Datatable CVS File Export, we've grabbed a custom DataTables built with all bells&whistles included from Download Builder page https://datatables.net/download/ and have just replaced stuff in    \civicrm\packages\jquery\plugins\DataTables\media\js\

However, changes will be obviously lost after civicrm core update. Is there any recommended technique to handle such things?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, answering my own question again. So, there are essentially 2 ways to achieve this:

1. Override  \civicrm\CRM\Core\Resources.php (copy it to your custom php directory first, in order to keep control on changes). It contains (quote) *List of core resources we add to every CiviCRM page.*
2. Use [hook_civicrm_coreResourceList(&$list, $region) {}](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/hook_civicrm_coreResourceList)

*(!! Attention: methods of adding 3rd-party resources, described at that page doesn't always work; we've ended up using drupal_add_js. Datatable initialization script has to be wrapped into drupal.behaviors than).*